# Can cross join be substituted with analytical query? Is cross join ultimately necessary in reporting?

Tags: sql

I am a new Business Analyst and am reviewing somebody else's SQL written for dashboard reporting. This includes some data that is researched and verified and if there it does not meet standards then it is entered in a bug's database. These are huge tables in terabytes and over millions of rows.
The query that I am looking at runs very slow. This query is created to run on the data, then create a view or materialized table and create a dashboard. I confused as to why the only cross joins, in combination with inner join can resolve this. Can cross join be substituted with the analytical query? Is cross join ultimately necessary in reporting?

Comment: It depends on architectural decisions and table normalisation state. Nothing is wrong with JOINs but you could try to remove them and increase the speed by using Materialized View and PL/SQL

Comment: You would need to provide more information about the data model and the query involved. The times to use cross-joins are typically when I need every row of a dataset to be potentially included in every possible category. E.g., if I am summing transactions and need a rolling total, so multiple time categories will contain a single transaction. If, e.g., you are categorizing bugs and each bug may be in multiple categories then cross-joining may be the only option to perform the analysis in one query. Often, such slow queries can be sped up by breaking into multiple separate, sequential queries